# How to Modify Code Between Product Flavors

Tags: java, android, android-productflavors

I'm creating a very simple app with a free and paid version, for this I'm using the great productFlavors feature in the Android Gradle plugin. I understand how the build.gradle file should be configured and have written it so my build options are;

- freeRelease
- freeDebug
- paidRelease
- PaidDebug

that looks as follows

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.someconfig
    }
}
productFlavors {
    free {
        packageName "com.somepackagename.appfree"
    }
    paid {
        packageName "com.somepackagename.appPaid"
    }
}
```

Basically, all I'm trying to do is restrict a few features and add AdMod to the free version, how would I do that? Do I add if-else statements in my main java classes that check to see if it's free or paid? or can I overwrite java classes in the free directory? How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You can encode things in the directory structure, e.g.:

```sh
src/
  main/                    # Common source and assets
    java/
    res/
    AndroidManifest.xml
  free/                    # Source and assets for the free flavour
    java/
    res/
    AndroidManifest.xml
  paid/                    # Source and assets for the paid flavour
    java/
    res/
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

The code and assets that are specific to one version or the other go into the specific directories. The manifests are merged. You can use the `FLAVOR` field generated into `BuildConfig.java` to base if-else statements on.

The [SourceSets and Dependencies](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies) section of the Android-Gradle-Plugin user guide explains this in greater detail.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I add if-else statements in my main java classes that check to see
>   if it's free or paid?

**Yes**, you have to add `if-else` in your `activities`/`fragments` to check the flavour:

```
private void javaCode() {
    if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("paid")) {
        doIt();
    else {
        showOnlyInPaidAppDialog();
    }
}
```

Source: [BuildConfig](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-BuildConfig)