# How to create a complicated Venn diagram in Android Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

A followup question to the [how to modify code between product flavors question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368607/how-to-modify-code-between-product-flavors/24706644): how would one create 3 flavors that includes code shared by 2 of the flavors, but not the 3rd?  Basically, I'm looking for a 3 circled venn diagram like [this](http://wc1.smartdraw.com/examples/content/examples/05_strategy_&_planning/venn_diagrams/3_circle_venn_diagram_l.jpg), where code can be specific to just 2 of the flavors.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to accomplish this using sourcesets (or, at least, sourcesets without symlinks for the sharing). Gradle for Android obviously has the ability to pull from multiple sourcesets, so I can't rule out the possibility that you could have a dedicated sourceset for the code shared by those two flavors, then somehow tell Gradle for Android to also use that sourceset.

Or, you could put the common code in a library, and include that library as a dependency only in those two flavors.

Or, you could put the common code in `main/`, and only reference it from those two flavors.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. It's probably for the best that this sort of complicated sourceset structure is not supported. What a mess to maintain!

Comment: Not sure if this will meet your needs exactly, but Xav's reply on [this `adt-dev` Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/JrpirWIGQWY) shows some promise.

Comment: Actually, that looks like exactly what I want! Thanks @CommonsWare!